# Why windows server 2016 shows 3.99 TB for windows Update Cleanup in disk cleanup?

Tags: windows, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I'm using windows server 2016 server and recently updated it. When I used `disk cleanup` for the first time saw this:

> Windows Update Cleanup 3.99 TB

Why windows is showing that update files are taking about 4TB of data while total disk partition is about 50GB?
Is it a Windows bug?

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug that comes with cumulative update KB 3201845.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I download this KB for Windows Server 2016 and updated, after restart OS resolved problem. Download address: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb3201845